# PHP - In which cases can an email not be accepted for delivery?

Tags: php, email, backend

With the following statement we will get a boolean whether the mail we try to send gets accepted for delivery or not:

```
if(mail($to $subject $message $headers))
```

Since I always get `true` even if I am not connected to the internet, I assume that this response has nothing to do with the fact if it gets sent for real or not. So in which cases can I get `false`? And where does this 'getting accepted for delivery' happens (on my computer, on the server, in the aether...)?

Comment: To (help) ensure delivery, the server should contain an SPF record. You can read up on this here http://www.openspf.org and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework - However, once mail goes out, it's beyond your control to know if the receiving end will accept it or not; the subject is too broad.

Comment: PHP doesn't actually send the email. It uses other 3rd party programs (ex: sendmail on linux) to do that for it. `mail()` returns the status of whether or not that program accepted the email. That program will add the email to a queue, process the queue, send the mail, etc. Mail only knows whether that program accepted the email. The return value is `true if the mail was accepted for delivery`, not whether it was actually delivered. Reasons for a false value would be sendmail not installed, not configured correctly or configured in some way that the call failed.

Comment: why was this tagged as `phpmailer`?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn thanks for your reply, actually my main question was how you could get a "false" response' and it seems like you were the only one who answered it :)

Answer (score 2):

The `mail()` function uses the system mailer - which can be sendmail, or a mail transfer agent directly. The return value only indicates that the message was delivered successfully to whatever intermediary your system is configured with (usually sendmail on linux systems).

If you need actual data on deliverability, you could use a third party mail service such as SendGrid or MailGun, etc, which use APIs to send and also can report back delivery status, and other data.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the php.net documentation,

> mail() Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for
>   delivery, FALSE otherwise. It is important to note that just because
>   the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will
>   actually reach the intended destination.

In other words, the mail() function returns true if he gets all the values he needs to send the mail. But cannot know if the mail was received or not because PHP is not the one sending the mail. The mail server (most likely exim) is.

There's a nice PHP library that can help you validate if an email is valid/exists and belongs to a user. It's called [kickbox](https://github.com/kickboxio/kickbox-php)

So before using the mail() function, you could run the email in kickbox and in combination with the returned true of mail() you can assume the mail was sent out as long as exim does his job.

You can also use an API like MailJet to send out your email in your name instead of using the servers mail server and receive a status report directly from the API to know if the mail server was successful or not in sending the mail.

Answer (score 0):

As most of the replies here already answered your question, may I suggest an alternative which is PHPMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)?

It's a library for sending emails in PHP and you can define the SMTP, account info and even attach files when sending out emails. It even allows for SMTP debugging of sorts as well using "$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;" for example.

Quite easy to use too. You can refer to the official tutorial here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion :) I will try it in the future in case I need it